# Is US 20130318346 A1 (Verizon) the patent currently used in adding X-UIDH to web traffic?

Tags: us8832436

US8832436, "Obtaining targeted services using a unique identification header (uidh)" states:

> store the unique identifier in the request to create a modified request; provide the modified request to a content provider identified by the request

This sounds like it would match "adding a header to an HTTP request".

Additionally, the patent text mentions "UIDH":

> Ad provider 155 may receive request 635 and may determine that the UIDH, obtained from request 635, matches a UIDH that is stored in a memory associated with Ad server 155. Ad server 155 may retrieve, from the memory, targeted content 640 (FIG. 6) that corresponds to the stored UIDH and may provide targeted content 640 to content provider 150. Content provider 150 may receive targeted content 640 and may combine the content 
>   with targeted content 640 to create a response 645 (FIG. 6). Content provider 150 may transmit, as response 645, the content and/or targeted content 640 to user device 110 via CMDS 210 and/or PGW 120. User device 110 may receive response 645 and may display the content and/or targeted content 640 on user device 110.

So, is this the patent supporting [the actions referenced here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8500131)?

Grant: http://www.google.com/patents/US8832436
Application: http://www.google.com/patents/US20130318346